# Can't migrate djangocms_text_ckeditor Improperly Configured

Tags: django-cms

Using Django 1.7
django-cms 3.0.9
djangocms-text-ckeditor 2.4.3

manage.py migrate djangocms_text_ckeditor gives an improperly configured error:

https://gist.github.com/e7c754d329eb22126b11

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.0.html - suggests there is work to do, but doesn't indicate what needs to be done to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The gist is not accessible.
Anyway, have you had a loot at http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.0.6.html#django-1-7-support and https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor#installation?

You must customize some settings to setup django CMS 3.0.x on Django 1.7

Comment: thanks - i'll follow your links.  Just curious - what did I do wrong with the gist?  Don't I just get the clone url?

Comment: i see the need for render_template.  I'm trying to migrate - I don't see how to change configurations to get that to work.

Comment: @RandO the gist was just blank (as in totally blank page) when I tried to open it
Now I can see and it's totally unrelated, actually :) The above links was related to setup CMS and text plugin to work with Django 1.7
WRT to your issue is 'djangocms_text_ckeditor' in INSTALLED_APPS? Apparently Django can't find the plugin template

Answer (score 0):

I commented out all the CMS applications.  got everything else working correctly.  And then added the applications back.  It began working correctly  after that.  No setting problem, no application order problem.  Weird.